# Angularjs : Code organisation of controllers

Tags: javascript, project-organization, angularjs

I used the angular seed (with the file index-async.html(dependencies loaded asynchronously)) in order to start my web project, but my controllers would need some reorganisation. I have now 3 files full of controllers (700+ lines). Is there an elegant way to load my controllers if I reorganize them in 10 files (and more in the future).

Also, more files means less merging conflicts (Yeah!!!)

Thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make extensive use of the `angular.module().controller()` syntax to group my controllers by module, which has greatly improved the organization of my angular code.  As an added benefit, your controllers are no longer globally name-spaced functions.

You can read more in the [Module API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module).

Comment: @cricardol During development I do manually added each .js file (each of which contain one angular module) to my index.html page.  Concatenating these files into one file can easily be included in a build process, however.

Comment: You can also add a static reference to a js file during development.  This static file gets automatically updated through projects like LiveReload or Grunt.js which concatenates files upon file changes.

Comment: link you added just pints to angular docs where thee is no real example of what you described.